# Sed to match first occurence between two strings

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have this command which will assign to var the match from output between string1 and string 2, the problem is there are multiple matches possible and i want just the first one to be assigned to var.
How is that possible?

```
var=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | sed -n '/"$string1"/,/"$string2"/p')
```

Comment: Pipe it to `head`?  `head -1`?

Comment: Piping to `head` works, i didn't had the reflex of piping and i concentrated just on sed, as they say piping is always your friend !

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/"$string1"/,/"$string2"/{:l p;n;/"$string2"/{p;Q};b l}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
var=$(<<<"$OUTPUT" sed '/'"$string1"'/,/'"$string2"'/!d;/'"$string2"'/q')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | sed -n '/"$string1"/,/"$string2"/ {p;q}')
```

but this return the string corresponding to $String1

```
var=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | sed -n '/"$string1"/,/"$string2"/ {H;/"$string2"/ {p;q}')
```

this return the first occurence of the group of line